# get yahoo contacts in android using oAuth

Tags: android, oauth, contacts, yahoo

this is my code to get yahoo contacts in android . 
i m able to get upto access token but while making GET request for contacts im getting signature invalid error.

i searched a lot but i couldnt found what im doing wrong. so anyone give me a hand.

```
public class YahooContacts extends BaseActivity {
    private final String TAG = "yahoo_auth";

    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "My_consumer_key";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "my_consumer_secret";



    private static final String CALLBACK_SCHEME = "http";
    private static final String CALLBACK_HOST = "www.something_unique_here.com";
    private static final String CALLBACK_URL = CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://"
            + CALLBACK_HOST;

    private String AUTH_TOKEN = null;
    private String AUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = null;
    private String AUTH_URL = null;
    private String USER_TOKEN = null;
    private String ACCESS_TOKEN = null;
    private String mUSER_GUID = null;

    private WebView mWebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yahoo_layout);
        mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        new getContactsTask().execute();

    }

    class getContactsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getAuthorizationToken();
            getUserAutherization();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    private void getAuthorizationToken() {

        String requestPath = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token?oauth_consumer_key="
                + CONSUMER_KEY
                + "&oauth_nonce="
                + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "x"
                + "&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT"
                + "&oauth_signature="
                + CONSUMER_SECRET
                + "%26"
                + "&oauth_timestamp="
                + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "&oauth_version=1.0"
                + "&xoauth_lang_pref=en-us"
                + "&oauth_callback=" + CALLBACK_URL;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(requestPath);
        try {
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            String[] data = responseBody.split("&");
            AUTH_TOKEN = data[0].replace("oauth_token=", "");
            AUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = data[1].replace("oauth_token_secret=", "");
            AUTH_URL = data[3].replace("xoauth_request_auth_url=", "");
            VIPLogger.info(TAG, "authToken" + AUTH_TOKEN);
            VIPLogger.info(TAG, "authToken secret" + AUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getUserAutherization() {
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(lWebviewClient);
        mWebview.loadUrl("https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token="
                + AUTH_TOKEN);
    }

    private void getAccessToken() {
        String requestPath = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token?oauth_consumer_key="
                + CONSUMER_KEY
                + "&oauth_nonce="
                + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "x"
                + "&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT"
                + "&oauth_signature="
                + CONSUMER_SECRET
                + "%26"
                + AUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
                + "&oauth_timestamp="
                + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "&oauth_version=1.0"
                + "&oauth_token="
                + AUTH_TOKEN
                + "&oauth_verifier="
                + USER_TOKEN;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(requestPath);
        try {
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            String[] data = responseBody.split("&");
            ACCESS_TOKEN = data[0].replace("oauth_token=", "");
            mUSER_GUID = data[5].replace("xoauth_yahoo_guid=", "");
            VIPLogger.info(TAG, "user guid: " + mUSER_GUID);
            VIPLogger.info(TAG, "Access token: " + ACCESS_TOKEN);
            getAllContacts();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            VIPLogger.error(TAG,
                    "error while fetching user guid and access token");
        }
    }

    WebViewClient lWebviewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                android.graphics.Bitmap favicon) {
            if (url.contains("vipitservice")) {
                mWebview.stopLoading();
                int lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf("=") + 1;
                VIPLogger.info(TAG, url.substring(lastIndex, url.length()));
                USER_TOKEN = url.substring(lastIndex, url.length());
                mWebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                getAccessToken();
            }
        };

    };

    private void getAllContacts() {


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        String host_url = "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/" + mUSER_GUID+ "/contacts";

        String nonce = ""+System.currentTimeMillis();
        String timeStamp = ""+(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L);




        try{
            String params = "?realm=yahooapis.com" 
                    + "&oauth_consumer_key=" + CONSUMER_KEY
                    + "&oauth_nonce="+nonce
                    + "&oauth_signature_method="+"HMAC-SHA1"
                    + "&oauth_timestamp="+timeStamp
                    + "&oauth_token="+URLDecoder.decode(ACCESS_TOKEN,"utf-8")
                    + "&oauth_version=1.0"

                    ;
            String baseString = "GET&"+encode(host_url)+encode(params);
            String signingKey = encode(CONSUMER_SECRET)+"&"+encode(AUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
            VIPLogger.info(TAG, "base string: " + baseString);
            String lSignature = computeHmac(baseString, signingKey);
            VIPLogger.info(TAG, "signature: " + lSignature);
            lSignature = encode(lSignature);
            VIPLogger.info(TAG, "signature enacoded: " + lSignature);

            String lRequestUrl = host_url
                                + "?realm=yahooapis.com"
                                + "&oauth_consumer_key="+CONSUMER_KEY
                                + "&oauth_nonce="+nonce
                                + "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1"
                                + "&oauth_timestamp="+timeStamp
                                + "&oauth_token="+ACCESS_TOKEN
                                + "&oauth_version=1.0"
                                + "&oauth_signature="+lSignature
                                ;
            VIPLogger.info(TAG, lRequestUrl.substring(1202));
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(lRequestUrl);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

            VIPLogger.info(TAG, "contacts response: " + responseBody);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            VIPLogger.error(TAG, "error while fetching user contacts");
        }



    }

    public String computeHmac(String baseString, String key) {
        try {
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    "HMAC-SHA1");
            mac.init(signingKey);
            byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
            String result = Base64.encodeToString(digest, Base64.URL_SAFE);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            VIPLogger.error(TAG, "error while generating sha");
        }
        return null;

    }

    public String encodeURIComponent(final String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        try {
            return URLEncoder.encode(value, "utf-8")
                    // OAuth encodes some characters differently:
                    .replace("+", "%20").replace("*", "%2A")
                    .replace("%7E", "~");
            // This could be done faster with more hand-crafted code.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }


        public  String encode(String input) {
            StringBuilder resultStr = new StringBuilder();
            for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
                if (isUnsafe(ch)) {
                    resultStr.append('%');
                    resultStr.append(toHex(ch / 16));
                    resultStr.append(toHex(ch % 16));
                } else {
                    resultStr.append(ch);
                }
            }
            return resultStr.toString().trim();
        }

        private  char toHex(int ch) {
            return (char) (ch < 10 ? '0' + ch : 'A' + ch - 10);
        }

        private  boolean isUnsafe(char ch) {
            if (ch > 128 || ch < 0)
                return true;
            return " %$&+,/:;=?@<>#%".indexOf(ch) >= 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue with this code. the trick is u need to encode all 'key' and 'values', then encode the parms again. . Remember that access_token comes as preencoded.

```
private void getAllContacts() {


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String host_url = "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/" + mUSER_GUID+ "/contacts";

    String nonce = ""+System.currentTimeMillis();
    String timeStamp = ""+(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L);

    try{
        String params = 
                ""+encode("oauth_consumer_key")+"=" + encode(CONSUMER_KEY)
                + "&"+encode("oauth_nonce")+"="+encode(nonce)
                + "&"+encode("oauth_signature_method")+"="+encode("HMAC-SHA1")
                + "&"+encode("oauth_timestamp")+"="+encode(timeStamp)
                + "&"+encode("oauth_token")+"="+ACCESS_TOKEN
                + "&"+encode("oauth_version")+"="+encode("1.0")

                ;
        String baseString = encode("GET")+"&"+encode(host_url)+"&"+encode(params);
        String signingKey = encode(CONSUMER_SECRET)+"&"+encode(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        VIPLogger.info(TAG, "base string: " + baseString);
        String lSignature = computeHmac(baseString, signingKey);
        VIPLogger.info(TAG, "signature: " + lSignature);
        lSignature = encode(lSignature);
        VIPLogger.info(TAG, "signature enacoded: " + lSignature);

        String lRequestUrl = host_url
                            + "?oauth_consumer_key="+CONSUMER_KEY
                            + "&oauth_nonce="+nonce
                            + "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1"
                            + "&oauth_timestamp="+timeStamp
                            + "&oauth_token="+ACCESS_TOKEN
                            + "&oauth_version=1.0"
                            + "&oauth_signature="+lSignature
                            ;
        //VIPLogger.info(TAG, lRequestUrl.substring(1202));
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(lRequestUrl);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        VIPLogger.info(TAG, "contacts response: " + responseBody);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        VIPLogger.error(TAG, "error while fetching user contacts");
    }

}
```