# Cycle Prohibited issue in yahoo integration in android

Tags: android

I want to get the yahoo contacts in my application. I am following the code from this url ([get yahoo contacts in android using oAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928169/get-yahoo-contacts-in-android-using-oauth?answertab=votes#tab-top)) but i am getting an cycle prohibited issue when i am trying to get  the oauth_token.can anybody please help me whether this issue is from developers(myside) or from yahoo.

Comment: We are facing similar issue, Couldn't solve it yet.

Before loading auth page, I tried clearing Cache and history of android  WebView as pointed out for browser URLs. But it did not fix this error.
Let us know if you are able to solve this problem

Comment: ok  .Actualy i got an auth page ,oauth_token and xoauth_yahoo_guid value only once. From later i am getting the issue(multi hop cycle detected ) . I have been working on this from two days but unable to resolve .Any ideas please share .

Comment: Did you try https protocol as mentioned here? http://www.walkswithme.net/yahoo-contact-list-reader-with-oauth-api-in-php#li-comment-28945